# Javac 1.8.0_25 has known bug - how to use different version?

Tags: java, travis-ci

My [travis build fails](https://travis-ci.org/tbsalling/aismessages/builds/41598821) - and I think it is because of [a known JDK-bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065315).

How can I force travis to use the 1.8.0_40 java compiler (instead of 1.8.0_25), so that I do not run into this compiler bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading could be an option, with following pre-install steps in your .travis.yml:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade -y oracle-java8-installer
```

but Travis CI environments are installing Oracle JDK 8 from [ppa:webupd8team/java](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) and as you can see [there](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=precise), WebUpd8 Team has not released yet a newer package than 1.8.0_25. So this method won't bring you 1.8.0_40 today.

Downgrading is also a possible approach:

```
before_install:
  - wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+files/oracle-java8-installer_8u11%2B8u6arm-1~webupd8~3_all.deb -O oracle-java8-installer.deb
  - sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-installer.deb
```

And it actually solves your problem: https://github.com/tbsalling/aismessages/pull/6 :)

Comment: Sadly they have now removed the 1.8.0_11 installer - but not yet included 1.8.0_40 - so will have to look for another fix until 1.8.0_40 gets included by the WebUpd8 team.

Comment: That's too bad that Webupd8 cannot provide a complete archive... I guess it is a storage capacity/cost question. It might be worth to contact them (or even Canonical) to explain the value of a complete .deb package archive. In fact, 1.8.0_40 is available in Webupd8 PPA, but unfortunately your project seems to fail due to another JDK8 bug. See more details in https://github.com/tbsalling/aismessages/pull/12 ...